# Is creme brulee supposed to be fatty?

Tags: flavor, creme-brulee

I just made creme brulee but it felt a lot like I am eating butter.

I know it should be made with ~35% fat cream so it makes sense to be "fatty". I just have never eaten "real" creme brulee with which to make a comparison and am not sure if it really should taste fatty like butter or if I did something wrong.

Comment: Maybe add your recipe and process?

Comment: I am not sure if your question is answerable. To me, butter and creme brulee taste differently. To others, it may taste so similar they declare it to be "the same". The limit when "fatty" becomes "too fatty" is subjective. From the simple description of "fatty", we cannot conclude if you did something wrong or if you just happen to not like properly made creme brulee.

Comment: @rumtscho, I see your point. Well, I didn't provide a recipe, because I was asking for creme brulee in general, like I said - I never ate "real" creme brulee, so I wanted to know if I got it close to real taste.

Comment: Am I understanding correctly that you are asking about texture/mouth feel rather than the actual taste/flavor?

Comment: @Cindy, I am actually asking about both. Like I said, I have never tried real creme brulee, so I'd like to know if it is normal for it to taste a lot like butter.

Answer (score 2):

No creme brulee should not resemble butter in any way. Not in taste nor in texture. Its consistency should be like that of a thick custard where the eggs determine the firmness of the custard. 
We tend to use single cream with 15% fat for our creme brulee. This works very well and leads to a lighter and less fattier result.

Comment: I was led to believe you should use creme with upward of 30% fat for creme brulee